# Setting a selected value of an html select based on cookie in Razor view engine

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, razor

I have a `<select>` element on a Razor view. It renders as a drop box with language values. I set language via custom cookies and a custom cookie aware view engine.

Let's say I have a cookie set (called `language`). I want to have a view render with a corresponding `<option>` marked as selected based on a cookie value. How can I control it with Razor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would put the select in a strongly typed partial view:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<Language>
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x,
                    new SelectList((List<Language>)ViewBag.AllLanguages,
                    "Id",
                    "Text",
                    Model==null?-1:Model.Id), "Choose Language")
```

I would actually set the value in my controller

```
public virtual ActionResult _MyAction()
{
    // get users language
    string selectedLanguage = "English"; // default
    if(Request.Cookies["language"] != null)
    {
        selectedLanguage = Request.Cookies["lang"].ToString();
    }

    // language list
    ViewBag.AllLanguages = context.Languages.ToList();

    // retrieve language from database - example using EF
    ViewBag.SelectedLanguage = context.Languages
                                      .FirstOrDefault(l=>l.Text==selectedLanguage);
```

and then in my main view

```
@Html.Partial("LanguageSelect", ViewBag.SelectedLanguage);
```

This keeps the logic of what language to select away from the presentation of the actual select list. And you could put all that logic in a shared method if it's used a lot.